# Жжение в желудке — прими Хилак форте / «Хилак форте»

Tags: кавычки

Как правильно?

> Жжение в желудке — прими Хилак форте / «Хилак форте».

Answer (score 1):

**Реклама** лекарственного препарата:

*Жжение в желудке — прими ***Хилак форте.****

**Пояснение**

1. Если имеется в виду лекарственный **препарат**, то правильно **без кавычек**. Это обычный (частотный) вариант, оригинальное название именно препарата:

*Описание препарата **Хилак форте** (капли для приема внутрь) основано на официальной инструкции, утверждено компанией-производителем в 2019 году.*

2. Но вот **другая** запись: *Когда ты бегемотик и у тебя болит животик. Как наладить работу ЖКТ? Купить пребиотик ***"ХИЛАК ФОРТЕ".****  Думаю, что можно записать так: Купить пребиотик ***"Хилак форте"***.

Здесь другое родовое слово —  ***пребиотик***, а они бывают на разной основе. Поэтому используются **кавычки.**

```
 Пребиотики – это вещества, которые стимулируют рост 
 полезных бифидо - и лактобактерий, то есть пробиотиков в 
 кишечнике. К ним относятся некоторые полисахариды и 
 органические кислоты, в том числе омега-3.
```

3. А вот такая запись: *Выписали мне от дисбактериоза **хилак форте**.*

Насколько это корректно? Думаю, что допускается **в чатах,** где названный препарат хорошо **известен.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (перечень, лекарственные препараты в кавычках)

В **[список](https://wer.ru/articles/kak-vybrat-probiotiki-dlya-kishechnika-spisok-preparatov/)** препаратов включены **лучшие пробиотики** для восстановления микрофлоры кишечника. Рейтинг основан на эффективности, безопасности и соотношении цена-качество.

№1 – «Нормофлорин-Д» (Бифилюкс, Россия)

№2 – «Бифиформ» (Ferrosan, Дания)  И т.д.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151750/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.